# Make navigation bar fixed after scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm attempting to make the navigation bar stick to the top, when the user scrolls down to the nav bar and then unstick when the user scrolls back up past the navbar. The [JSFIDDLE is here](http://jsfiddle.net/jpXjH/). Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Update: I understand that this can't be implemented through CSS & HTML. What would be the best way to implement this?

```
    <section class="main">
     <div id="wrap">

            <div id="featured">
         <div class="wrap">      
      <div class="textwidget">
        <div class="cup"><img src="#""></div>
    <div id="header"></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>
    <div class="whiteboard">
             <h1><a href="#">HELLO GUYS</a></h1>


        </div>
    </div>
 <div class="bg1"> <h2> WE ARE AN EVENTS MANAGEMENT COMPANY BASED IN LONDON. </h2></div>
```

& the CSS

```
          .main{text-align:center;}

          h1{
              -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
                  display:inline-block;
                font: 800 1.313em "proxima-nova",sans-serif; 
                padding: 10px 10px;
                margin: 20px 20px;
                letter-spacing: 8px;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                  font-size:3.125em;
                  text-align: center; 
                  max-width: 606px;
          line-height: 1.45em;
          position: scroll;
              background-color:#e94f78;
              text-decoration: none;
              color:yellow;
              background-image:url;
          }

          h1 a{
            text-decoration: none;
            color:yellow;
                    padding-left: 0.15em;
          }

          h2{
              -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
                  display:inline-block;
                font: 800 1.313em "proxima-nova",sans-serif; 
                letter-spacing: 8px;
                margin-top: 100px;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                  font-size:3.125em;
                  text-align: center; 
          line-height: 1.45em;
          position: scroll;
              text-decoration: none;
              color:white;
              z-index: -9999;
          }

          h2 a{
            text-decoration: none;
            color:white;
                    padding-left: 0.15em;
          }

          h5{

          position: absolute;
                  font-family:sans-serif; 
                  font-weight:bold; 
                  font-size:40px; 
                  text-align: center; 
                  float: right;
                  background-color:#fff;
                  margin-top: -80px;
                  margin-left: 280px;
          }

          h5 a{

            text-decoration: none;
            color:red;
          }

          h5 a:hover{

            color:yellow;
          }

          #text1{
              -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
                  display:inline-block;
                font: 800 1.313em "proxima-nova",sans-serif; 
                margin: 20px 20px;
                letter-spacing: 8px;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                  font-size:3.125em;
                  text-align: center; 
                  max-width: 606px;
          line-height: 1.45em;
          position: scroll;
              background-color:#E94F78;

          }

          #text1 a{
              color:yellow;
              text-decoration: none;
                  padding-left: 0.15em;


          }

          #text1 a:hover{

              text-decoration: none;
              cursor:pointer;
          }

          .whiteboard{
              background-image:url(http://krystalrae.com/img/krystalrae-2012-fall-print-leopard-sketch.jpg);
              background-position: center;
              padding: ;
              background-color: #fff;
              z-index: 1000;
          }

          .bg{
            height:2000px;
            background-color:#ff0;
            background-image:url(http://alwayscreative.net/images/stars-last.jpg);
            position:relative;
            z-index: -9999;

          }
          .bg1{
            background-image:url(http://alwayscreative.net/images/stars-last.jpg);
            z-index: -9999;
            height:1000px;
          }
          /* Header */
          #wrap {
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 0;
            width: 100%;
          }

          #featured {
            background: #E94F78 url(http://www.creativityfluid.com/wp-content/themes/creativityfluid/images/img-bubbles-red.png) no-repeat top;
            background-size: 385px 465px;
            color: #fff;
            height: 535px;
            overflow: hidden;
            position: relative;
            z-index: -2;
          }


          #featured .wrap {
            overflow: hidden;
            clear: both;
            padding: 70px 0 30px;
            position: fixed;
            z-index: -1;
            width: 100%;
          }


          #featured .wrap .widget {
            width: 80%;
            max-width: 1040px;
            margin: 0 auto;
          }

          #featured h1,
          #featured h3,
          #featured p {
            color: yellow;
            text-shadow: none;
          }

          #featured h4{
            color:white;
            text-shadow:none;
          }

          #featured h4 {
            margin: 0 0 30px;
          }

          #featured h3 {
            font-family: 'proxima-nova-sc-osf', arial, serif;
            font-weight: 600;
            letter-spacing: 3px;
          }

          #featured h1 {
            margin: 0;
          }

          .textwidget{
            padding: 0;
          }

          .cup{
            margin-top:210px;
            z-index: 999999;
          }

          .container{font-size:14px; margin:0 auto; width:960px}
          .test_content{margin:10px 0;}
          .scroller_anchor{height:0px; margin:0; padding:0;background-image:url()}
          .scroller{background:#FFF;
            background-image:url(http://krystalrae.com/img/krystalrae-2012-fall-print-leopard-sketch.jpg);
           margin:0 0 10px; z-index:100; height:50px; font-size:18px; font-weight:bold; text-align:center; width:960px;}
```

Comment: hi i don't think what you want, done with `css and html` only maybe you need a `jquery or javascript`

Answer (score 2):

This "sticky" behavior you are referring to has become popular enough over the web that some people suggested it should be implemented as a CSS property like 'position: sticky' however right now and for the foreseeable future it is impossible to make a "sticky element" without the use of Javascript.

```
var element = document.getElementById('navBar')
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
     element.getBoundingClientRect().top < 0 ? 
     element.classList.add('stuck') : 
     element.classList.remove('stuck');
});
```

where in CSS `.stuck {position: fixed;}`

... something like that

Comment: Unfortunately `element.getBoundingClientRect().top` will always be `0` when it has the class `stuck`. So it will work initially to stick it but won't unstick on the scroll up.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it something like this :

http://jsfiddle.net/ux41b606

HTML:

```
<div id="image">Some image</div>
<div id="scroller">Some controls</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    height: 3000px;
    top: 0;
}
#image {
    width: 100%;
    background: #444;
    height: 50px;
}
#scroller{
    height:100px;
    background:#ccc;
}
.stuck{
    position:fixed;
    z-index:100;
    width:100%;
    top:0;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 50) {
        $('#scroller').addClass('stuck');
    } else {
        $('#scroller').removeClass('stuck');
    }
});
```

after scroll 50 px it will change the css of scroller.

this may be a good start

Comment: Don't just paste links to jsfiddle. Add at least the relevant parts into the answer to avoid link rot.

Answer (score 0):

it works for me

```
window.addEventListener( 'scroll', function() {
  // if scroll down after 45px (position Y)
  if (window.scrollY > 45) {
    document.querySelector('nav').style.position = 'fixed'
    document.querySelector('nav').style.top = '0'
  } else {
    document.querySelector('nav').style.position='none'
  }
});
```